# Display a view controller from appDelegate based on custom URL schema

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My app is using Storyboards. I want to post the hierarchy here:

view Controller >  tab bar controller > navigation controller > TableViewController > DetailViewController

This detail view controller has an identifier I set through interface builder also.

Select an item on the table shows a detail view.

I have enabled custom URLs in my app and everything works fine except and receives a call from other apps by using myappname://uniqueid

I want to display the Detail View I spoke about earlier when I recieve a custom URL call but I don't know how.

I have instantiated the view controller using its identifier but I don't know how to display it without throwing an error.

How can I show the view in this storyboard directly from appdelegate openUrl:source application method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to have a Notification from the AppDelagate to all view Controller and when the correct view Controller receives this notification from AppDelegate custom URL delegate, the view can be loaded modally.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get your UI in a known, ready state, since there's no telling where it will be when the call comes in.  To be ready, you need to have a handle to the tab bar, and be able to convert the uniqueid on the URL into the part of your model that the detail vc is supposed to inspect.

It should look something like this (with liberal guessing about your existing code):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

    // get the ui to a known state
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = kTHE_NAVIGATION_VC_INDEX;
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    // parse the url to get uniqueId
    // the uniqueId specifies an object in your model that you want to have
    // inspected by the detail view controller?  you'll need that object...
    MyObject *detailObject = [self.myModel objectWithUniqueId:uniqueId];

    // the detail vc probably has an init like this?
    DetailVC *detailVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithModel:detailObject];

    [nav pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

**Edit**

To give your app delegate access to it's tabBarController, you can set up a property like this:

```
// AppDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

// AppDelegate.m, after @implementation
@synthesize tabBarController=_tabBarController;
```

Are you using a storyboard segue to get from the splash vc to the main app?  I am going to guess YES.  Is there more than one segue from the splash view controller  to the main app?  I'm going to guess NO.  If either of these guesses is wrong, you'll need to adjust this code...

```
// SplashViewController.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.tabBarController = tabBarController;
}
```

Comment: What u mean by get the UI to a ready state? I'm parsing the URL arguments and getting the detail view to display the right object but just didn't know how to push the view.

Comment: Ready state means ready to push the detail view controller (see the code).  The last line shows how to push the view controller.

Comment: i tried it, doesn't work for me. I throws an error for self.tabBarController. I have made the whole thing using storyboards of iOS5. Please edit your answer with a solution. I think we have to instanstiateViewController from storyboard and somehow push it to screen. But appdelegate has no connection to this view controller.

Comment: hey @danh i have added more details on the view hierarchy and please keep in mind i'm using storyboards in the app. Can you revise your answer. thank you so much for your help dan

Comment: @carbonr - I'll try, but I'm not sure I understand your description of the hierarchy.  Do you really have a regular view controller at the very bottom with a tab bar vc on top of it?  How is that tab bar vc presented, modally?  I think I understand that one of the tabs is a navigation controller with a table view controller as it's root, and it's clear that the table vc does a push to the detail vc, but I'm lost about who is modally presenting who.

Comment: Please bear in mind that those container vc's have special relationships with the vc's they contain.  E.g. the tab bar vc has an array of vc's for it's tabs, and the navigation vc has a stack, with the bottom vc called the root.  The 2 ways for one vc to present another are: any one can modally present any other on top of itself or - within a navigation vc - one vc can push another on top of itself.

Comment: I have a splash view controller then it shows My main controller which is Tab Controller - inside it are 4 controllers... first is a tableView controller which is embedded in navigation controller. This tableView is again connected to a detailed view controller(pushed).

Comment: @carbonr - Now I think I understand.  Your splash vc modally presents the application, and it is underneath your "real" app all of the time.  The code I suggested is correct, but your app delegate needs to have a handle to that tab bar controller.  Earlier, you said that self.tabBarController "throws an error", but I think you meant "doesn't compile".  I'm going to edit my answer to show you how to get to your tabBarController from the app delegate.